# Using INDEX to reference a cell containing a HYPERLINK command

Tags: excel, hyperlink, reference, indexing, cell

Currently I have the following set up (simplified):

[image]

With the formulae:
[image]

How would I change this to make the result in A7:E7 (e.g. Google) into a hyperlink to the address stored in the result's reference cell (e.g. "www.google.com" in cell A2)?

Many thanks,

Alex

Comment: I'm not understanding this. Dou want to insert a hyperlink in A7 based on the choice made in C2? Are you keeping all three addresses in A2:A4? Will they be addresses or hyperlinks?

Comment: Yes, I want the contents of A7 to be the same as the resultant cell (either A2, A3 or A4). So if I make my choice by clicking on cell C2 (google, or option 1), cell E4 will contain the selected option's number, and A7 will accordingly become a hyperlink to www.google.com. user3514930's answer gives what I want, but means that I have to split A2:A4 into two columns. Is there a formula that I can put into A7 which yields the desired result, without having to change anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Following the scheme :

[image]

**Using EXCEL Function:**
you can split in two columns the Hyperlink and use in the formula of Result:

```
=HYPERLINK(INDEX(B2:B4;D2);INDEX(A2:A4;D2))
```

**Using VBA:**
In a module add the Function:

```
Public Function Addr(x As Range) As String
    Addr = x.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
End Function
```

and in the Result use:

```
=HYPERLINK(Addr(INDEX(A6:A8;D2));INDEX(A6:A8;D2))
```

**Using Name Manager:**
In the name Manager (Under menu Formulas) add a name called **"KKK",** inserting:

```
=GET.FORMULA(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$12:$A$14;Sheet1!$D$2))
```

and in the result cell:

```
=HYPERLINK(MID(KKK;1+FIND("""";KKK);FIND(";";KKK)-(2+FIND("""";KKK)));INDEX(A12:A14;D2))
```

Work ONLY if it's a FORMULA, Don't work if are a Link like A6.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without splitting into two separate columns?